# Does Core Data actually save any changes to disk before updating NSFetchedResultsControllers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

This is a very specific question and I've been bitten by it just now, so to save others some time and agony, here's my problem in-depth and the solution.

When you save the main context, for instance, and it triggers NSFetchedResultsController delegate callbacks, can you depend upon the fact that your save has actually completed, and could you safely perform new fetch requests within those callbacks assuming that the currently saved data will be included?

The answer is NO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have active NSFetchedResultsController's (NSFRC) in your app that have a delegate set and are monitoring changes to relevant objects, then here's a small undocumented caveat that all Core Data developers should be aware of. If you perform a save on the main context, and have NSFRC's working on the main context, then calling `save:` on the main context will actually update the NSFRC first and call the `willChangeContent:..`, `didChangeContent:..`, etc. callbacks on your NSFRC delegate before actually saving the MOC contents to disk.

The reason why this could be problematic is if you try to execute a new fetch request using a resultType of `NSDictionaryResultType` *inside those NSFRC callbacks*, then your fetch request won't include any current changes. By current changes, I mean those changes for which your NSFRC callbacks were called in the first place.

The reason why you won't see those changes is because setting the resultType to `NSDictionaryResultType` turns off the `includesPendingChanges` property. So the fetch request only gets changes directly from the disk and doesn't merge any local changes from the context.

I can somewhat understand the reasons why arbitrary fetch requests using a dictionary result type don't merge unsaved results from the context since the dictionaries could have any arbitrary structure, while the MOC is modeling objects and relationships in a graph, however, the part that was interesting and surprising to me was that the NSFRC delegate got update callbacks before a save was actually done.

Here's some ASCII art:

```
    1. save Main MOC --> | 2. NSFRC callbacks --> | 3. actual save happens here
                         |          |             |            
                         |          |             |
                         |          ▼             |
                         | NSDictionaryResultType |
                         | fetch requests won't   |
                         | see any changes from   |
                         | this current save, but |
                         | regular fetch requests |
                         | will see those changes |
```

PS: Core Data is an object-graph management framework that runs on limited performance devices. Sometimes you gotta optimize.

Comment: +1 for ASCII art. Core Data *is* an "undocumented caveat" but let's not go into that right now.

Comment: @matt: ▼ = U+25BC is not ASCII :-)  +1 though for interesting information.

Comment: @MartinR - I was hoping to sneak it in there, but well caught. Touché!

Comment: That is because FRC watches `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification`, which is generated as a result of processing pending changes.  Once the current user-event is complete, pending changes are processed, so saving is not required for the FRC to see the changes to the MOC.  Pending changes are processed immediately when you call `save`, before the save happens.  So, your callback is being invoked because the changes are noticed, not because the context has been saved.