# Fetch request returns old data

Tags: ios, macos, core-data, nsfetchrequest, nsnotification

I'm getting outdated results when executing a fetch request upon a `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification`.

As an example, consider directories with documents that can be deleted logically with a boolean attribute (`softDeleted`). The fetch request should return all directories that have at least one non-deleted document (`directoriesWithDocuments`).

The initial state is single directory with a single deleted document. `directoriesWithDocuments` returns an empty array.

The following code restores the document by setting the `softDeleted` boolean to `NO`.

```
[_context.undoManager beginUndoGrouping];
[_context.undoManager setActionName:@"undelete"];
document.softDeleted = @(NO);
NSError *error;
BOOL success = [_context save:&error]; // This triggers the notification
[_context.undoManager endUndoGrouping];
```

The save triggers a `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification`. I expected `directoriesWithDocuments` to return the directory, but instead it still returns an empty array.

```
- (void)objectsDidChangeNotification:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSArray *objects = [self directoriesWithDocuments]; // Still empty!
}
```

Yet, if I execute `directoriesWithDocuments` **after** saving the context, either right away or in the next run loop, it returns the directory as expected.

This is the code of the fetch request:

```
- (NSArray*)directoriesWithDocuments
{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY documents.softDeleted == NO"];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Directory"];
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate;
    fetchRequest.includesPendingChanges = YES; // Just in case
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *objects = [_context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    return directories;
}
```

I suspect that the context has some kind of cache for fetch requests that is not cleared until the notification is handled. Is this how Core Data is expected to behave? Or am I doing something wrong?

### Workaround

I'm currently delaying the execution of the fetch request like this:

```
- (void)objectsDidChangeNotification:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        // HACK: Give time to Core Data to process pending changes or invalidate caches
        NSArray *objects = [self directoriesWithDocuments]; // Returns the directory as expected
    }];

}
```

### Experiments

Per @MikePollard's suggestion, I checked the returned value of `directoriesWithDocuments` in `NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification` and `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`. The results are (in order):

1. `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification`: empty (wrong)
2. `NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification`: empty (wrong)
3. `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`: 1 directory (correct)

Comment: Are you sure you're doing all work within the same NSManagedObjectContext?

Comment: I'd be interested to hear what results you get if you call `directoriesWithDocuments` as a result of the  `NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification` and also the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` notification instead?

Comment: @MariusFalkenbergWaldal Yes.

Comment: It strikes me that the predicate is going to be translated into a SQL statement so until the save hits the DB you're not going to get the result you want ... (Not that'd you'd image that from just reading the NSFetchRequest documentation.)

Comment: @MikePollard Edited the question to include the results.

Comment: Is '1 directory' the correct answer?

Comment: Then I suspect this is that case. i.e. the fetch is being done directly against the SQL DB and not taking into account the changed state of the context. I bet if you turn on `-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1` you'll see the SQL statement.

Comment: @MikePollard You're correct. Maybe you should post it as an answer. Any ideas on how to work around this? I fear that since it's impossible to know if a fetch request will be done against the SQL DB or not, then it's not safe to do any query synchronously in `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49163/discussion-between-mike-pollard-and-hpique)

Comment: Another related caveat that is worth noting - if you change the fetch request's resultType to be Dictionary, then it automatically turns off includesPendingChanges - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893794/does-core-data-actually-save-any-changes-to-disk-before-updating-nsfetchedresult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It strikes me that the predicate is going to be translated into a SQL statement so until the save hits the DB you're not going to get the result you want ... (Not that'd you'd image that from just reading the `NSFetchRequest` documentation.)

So try doing the fetch as a result of the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`.

I bet if you turn on -com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1 you'll see the SQL statement.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it looks like you have a boolean attribute called "deleted" defined in your model.

I recall that doing so can be a significant problem because it conflicts (at a KVC level) with NSManagedObject `isDeleted`. You might want to change that just to make sure it's not the culprit.

### Edit

> Thanks for replying. I used deleted as a simple example; it's not the
>   actual attribute I'm using. Will change it to softDeleted to avoid
>   confusion

I've updated my suggestion below to match the `softDeleted` in your example.

---

That said, I think what's at work here boils down to the question of what constitutes a "change" for `includesPendingChanges = YES`.

Before the context has completed its save, the only 'change' is to Document entities, not Directory entities.

So when the fetch request includes pending changes, there are no Directory entities with any pending changes so you end up with the previous results.

To test that theory, give this a shot:

```
[_context.undoManager beginUndoGrouping];
[_context.undoManager setActionName:@"delete"];
document.softDeleted = @(NO);
[document.directory willChangeValueForKey:@"documents"] // any attribute will do really
[document.directory didChangeValueForKey:@"documents"]
NSError *error;
BOOL success = [_context save:&error];
[_context.undoManager endUndoGrouping];
```

What you're doing with the fake will/did changeValueForKey is to "dirty" the associated Directory object. My guess is that it will then be considered "changed" and, as such, included the fetch results.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I used `deleted` as a simple example; it's not the actual attribute I'm using. Will change it to `softDeleted` to avoid confusion.